# Plot for a list of parameters

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I found the following possibility to plot a function for a table of parameters:

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[a^2 + parameter, {parameter, 0, 10, 2.5}], {a, -10, 10}]
```

However, I'd need to plot for a list of parameters, say

```
{parameter,1,2.5,3,7.8,9.572}
```

How can this be done? My search always directs me to this table approach and the following presents all plots in the same color, which is not really what I want:

```
 Plot[(a^2 + parameter) /. parameter -> {1, 2.5, 3, 7.8, 9.572}, {a, -10, 10}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try (note the new curly brackets):

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[a^2 + parameter, {parameter, {1, 2.5, 3, 7.8, 9.572}}], {a, -10, 10}]
```

[image]